# Render field collection multiple times on node.tpl.php

Tags: entities

I have created a custom view mode for field collections with this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().
 */
function view_modes_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['field_collection_item']['view modes']['myviewmode'] = array(
    'label' => t('My view mode'),
    'custom settings' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

And I'm trying to render the field in the node.tpl.php using the view mode with this code:

```
$display = array(
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'type' => 'myviewmode',
);
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_page_collection', $display);
print render($output);
```

But the field is rendering with the default view mode, not with the custom one I created. Is there a way to render it using the new view mode??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should read manual for [field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function.

1. **Do not use inside node (or any other entity) templates**; use render($content[FIELD_NAME]) instead.
2. Do not use to display all fields in an entity; use field_attach_prepare_view() and field_attach_view() instead.
3. The field_view_value() function can be used to output a single formatted field value, without label or wrapping field markup.